# Output line breaks from database

Tags: php

In my bio column in my database table I have this:

This is a test.
 Break 1.
 
 Break 2.

I'm trying to output the text from the table column on my page like this:

```
<?php echo escape (nl2br($data->bio)); ?>
```

But my output is returning like this on my webpage:

```
This is a test.<br /> Break 1.<br /> <br /> Break 2.
```

How can I make the line breaks output correctly?

This is my escape function:

```
<?php
function escape($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: `escape` is your issue, assuming it does what I think it does. Switch the order you call the 2 functions.

Comment: @WesleyMurch yup that solved the problem. I'll have to double check my escape function.

Also why the double down votes on this question?

Comment: It's just an obvious error, that's likely why the downvotes.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I see. Seemed like a valid question to me, hopefully someone else might find it useful.

Comment: Votes don't measure "validity" necessarily. You can ask a dumb, valid question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `<?php echo nl2br (escape($data->bio)); ?>`